# Dynamically creating an html table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to create a table based on user input (actually two or three tables depending on the user input..) using Javascript, I am very much native to PHP and have already got this working in PHP, however i would like the user to be able to see the table before the query it. I found a script on here that partially did what I wanted and have attempted to edit it (I found it surprisingly similar to PHP) Basically it calculates the total amount of cells (ports) splits it by rows and columns, the "super" column is used if the user would like it to be split into multiple tables, which align next to each other, hence the div tag. Here's my JS:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable()
{
var num_ports = document.getElementById('ports').value;
var num_super = document.getElementById('super').value;
var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
var tbody = '';
var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
for( var i=0; i<num_super; i++){
    var theader = '<div><table border="1">\n';
        for(u=1; u<=num_row; u++){
          tbody += '<tr>';
            for( var j=0; j<colStart; j++)
            {
            tbody += '<td>';
            tbody += 'Cell ' + i + ',' + j;
            tbody += '</td>'
            }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
var tfooter = '</table></div>';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
<label>Ports: <input type="text" name="ports" id="ports"/></label><br />
<label>Super Columns: <input type="text" name="super" id="super"/></label><br />
<label>Rows: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />
<label>Columns: <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols"/></label><br/>
<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the final output looks like after it has been processed by PHP (ports:24, col:6, rows:2, super:2):

[image: table]

Here is a js fiddle that I threw together:
http://jsfiddle.net/9SnLB/

Currently, when I click the button nothing happens, but, I suppose that is my first issue, but am I going about the setup correctly? Why wont the button run the function?

Comment: for($u=1; $u<=$row; $u++) <-- is this a valid Javascript?

Comment: @AliBassam is a for loop not vaild js?

Comment: @JohnDoe: It is, but `$u` should be `var $u` (to keep it local). The most common use of `$` in variable names is to prefix jQuery objects, so it might throw some people off.

Comment: I meant the variables, looks like PHP, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @AliBassam wow i got my languages confused i guess. `$` is used to set a variable in php, ill change it but i dont think thats my problem..

Comment: @Ali: yes, it's fine, a `$` is a valid character to use in variable-names (which is why (and how, of course) libraries, such as jQuery, can use it). Admittedly it'd be better if the new variables were defined with `var`, to prevent pollution of the global environment, but it's still valid, regardless.

Comment: Please delete php tag and css for good measure in your question because your question has nothing to do with php or css

Comment: @peterm got it no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes. One you didn't close the function bracket, ie a missing } at the end. The second is you used $row instead of the variable you created num_rows. For some reason it doesn't work in the fiddle, it does however work locally. The fiddle is saying the createTable function is undefined.

```
function createTable()
{
    var num_ports = document.getElementById('ports').value;
    var num_super = document.getElementById('super').value;
    var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
    var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
    var tbody = '';
    var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
    for( var i=0; i<num_super; i++){
        var theader = '<div><table border="1">\n';
            for($u=1; $u<=num_rows; $u++){
              tbody += '<tr>';
                for( var j=0; j<colStart; j++)
                {
                tbody += '<td>';
                tbody += 'Cell ' + i + ',' + j;
                tbody += '</td>'
                }
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var tfooter = '</table></div>';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
}
```

Comment: Yup that got her working,  almost. for some reason i didnt split them into two tables, its just one big one, but its certainly progress.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = [["a1","a2","a3"]["b1","b2","b3"]["c1","c2","c3"]];
for(x = table.length;x > 0;x--) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for(y = table[x].length;y > 0;y--) {
    document.write("<td>"+y+"</td>");
  }
document.write("</tr>");
}
```

Sorry if the syntax is wrong. You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your jsFiddle framework to "no wrap (head)" and correct errors in the javascript.  "no wrap (head)" will allow access the function.  The "for ($u=1" loop is missing the close brace and $row should be num_rows. The "for (j=0" loop is missing a semicolon at the last "tbody=".

here's the corrected js.

```
function createTable() {
var num_ports = document.getElementById('ports').value;
var num_super = document.getElementById('super').value;
var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
var tbody = '';
var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
for (var i = 0; i < num_super; i++) {
    var theader = '<div><table border="1">\n';
    for ($u = 1; $u <= num_rows; $u++) {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < colStart; j++) {
            tbody += '<td>';
            tbody += 'Cell ' + i + ',' + j;
            tbody += '</td>';
        }
    }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
var tfooter = '</table></div>';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
```

}