# How to import data from a xml link to a HTML website

Tags: html, xml, web

I'm setting up a new website with all the live currency from a bank.
The bank provides us with a link for the xml file.

```
https://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml
```

My question is how can I import the data from the provided link and make a table on my HTML website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript. So first you can get all the data from the XML in an Array like this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var currencies = xml.getElementsByTagName("Rate");
for(var i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
    $currency = currencies.attributes["currency"];
    $value = currencies.nodeValue;
}
```

This is how you get the data from the XML.

Here is a good explanation how you dynamically create an html table. [Dynamically creating an html table with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554376/dynamically-creating-an-html-table-with-javascript) 
I hope this helps